# Rs232 serial from Windows 10 App

Tags: serial-port, windows-10, tablet

I have a Panasonic Tablet that runs Windows 10 x64, and it has a UHF RFID chip inside that's made available through a virtual COM  PORT (like a USB - rs232 cable)  - 19200 bps, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit.

How can I access this COM port from a Windows App? I want to develop a simple touch app, I know how to communicate to this chip, but I can't find out how to just open the connection. Which language is better for developing an app (for tablet use)  that has this hardware communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows OS has a set of API functions that allows to work with any COM port:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The CreateFile API function allows to open the necessary port and communicate through it.

You may use any popular programming language. Most of them has a build-it or 3-rd party library.